# Не меняется значение в input

Tags: javascript

В `input` с индексами **a**,**b**,**c** вписываются значения. Если в **a** какой-либо символ или строка совпадает с **b**, то совпавшие символы или строки меняются на **c**:

```js
function Dot() {
  var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
  var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
  var c = document.getElementById('c').value;

  var av = a.length;
  var bv = b.length;
  var cv = c.length;

  if (bv === cv) {
    var w1;
    for (var i = 0; i < av; i++) {
      w1 = a.substr(i, bv);
      if (w1 == b) {
        a.replace(w1, c);
      }
    }
  }
}

var bot = document.getElementById('bot');
bot.addEventListener('click', Dot);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a"></br>
<input type="text" id="b"></br>
<input type="text" id="c"></br>
<button id="bot">Применить</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Две главные ошибки:

- неиспользование результата вызова `a.replace`,
- неприсвоение нового значения `input.value`.

По поводу логики замены частей строки могут быть вопросы - если в результате замены создается новый заменяемый кусок.

```
function Dot(){
  ...
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    ...
    a = a.replace(w1, c);
    ...
  ...
  document.getElementById('a').value = a;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function Dot() {
  console.log('Click');
  var a = document.getElementById('a');
  var b = document.getElementById('b');
  var c = document.getElementById('c');

  var av = a.value.length;
  var bv = b.value.length;
  var cv = c.value.length;

  if (bv === cv) {
    var w1;
    for (var i = 0; i < av; i++) {
      w1 = a.value[i]; // Only character
      // Using includes
      if (b.value.includes(w1)) { // matches
        a.value = a.value[i].replace(w1, c.value);
      }
    }
  }
}

var bot = document.getElementById('bot');
bot.addEventListener('click', Dot);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="a"></br>
<input type="text" id="b"></br>
<input type="text" id="c"></br>
<button id="bot">Применить</button>
```